# Can I localize an android application even when orientation changes?

Tags: android

I have a over flow menu from where language is clicked to get singlechoiceitems(list of languages). I have written this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder languageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            languageDialog.setTitle(R.string.chooseLanguage);
            final String[] languageOptions = { "English", "Nepali" };
            languageDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(languageOptions, 0,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == 0) {
                                setLanguage("es");
                            } else if (which == 1) {
                                setLanguage("ne");
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            languageDialog.show();
for list of Dailog and 
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setLanguage(String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    MainActivity.this.recreate();
} method to set locale
```

The problem is that on screen orientation change the language changes back to device language, why?anything I am missing?
I have made changes in anroid manifest file as I read but no solutions worked for me. Any help?

Comment: Use lifecycle method of Activity/Fragment and store/Retrieve data using lifecycle methods when orientation is changes.

Comment: would you like to give me some examples?

Comment: use some sharedpreference to store data at the time of destroy() method and read that in oncreate() by this you can show the saved language.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in *AnroidMenifest.xml* file in particular activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|layoutDirection|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, unfortunately changing language isn't a thing that Android likes. To make it work you need to call your setLanguage method in EACH activity before onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
changing orientation destroy activity and **recreate** it so when it **recreated** it changes to language that set in **oncreate** method.you have to save value in **saveinstatestate** and check on **oncreate** method

if(saveinstatntate!=null)`enter code here`
{
//then set the saved language
}
else
{
//defaultvalue
}
```

Comment: I am calling the method from alert dailog not inside onCreate method .. look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should add in your Android Manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
```

In your class you should have these imports:

```
import java.util.Locale; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.res.Configuration; 
import android.content.res.Resources; 
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
```

and the localization code should look like this:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) 
{ 
myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = myLocale; 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
startActivity(refresh); 
finish();
}
```

Please read: [How to change language of app when user selects language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-to-change-language-of-app-when-user-selects-language)

Read also:

[Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

[Set-up the application Language in Android Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414013/set-up-the-application-language-in-android-preferences)

Comment: I have read them and tried didnt work ... what is AndroidLocalize.class here

Comment: AndroidLocalize.class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343220/how-to-change-the-language-of-android-app-from-within

Comment: In my case its MainActivity .. I have tried with it .. didn't work

Comment: Please read them again, it might be problem that you're using both: in AndroidManifest declaration and in class method onConfigurationChange